# Several dataseries with hours+minutes on x-axis

Tags: excel, graph, scatter-plot

I'm trying to make an Excel scatter plot with data such as this

series 1:

```
[time]  [data]
10:05    2.1
10:30    1.8
11:15    3.1
```

series 2:

```
[time]  [data]
10:15    2.4
10:35    2.1
11:25    3.4
```

where each series is shown as a line in the scatterplot.
How is this done?
The problem seems to be that the x-values are not the same for the different series.
I whould like an x-axis running from say 10:00 to 12:00.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you don't want to have to insert blanks and intermesh the two series of data, just create 2 distinct series in 4 columns, and then reference each series individually:

[image: Data and scatter graph]

The series are defined as follows:

[image: Series 1]
[image: Series 2]